# IntelliJ not pointing to correct location

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I cannot open my IntelliJ from the Task Manager, App List, or Rofi. Doing so will only give me this error:

> Could not find the program '/home/user/.local/share/Trash/files/idea-IC-223.8617.56/bin/idea.sh'

I can only open IntelliJ by going to its installation directory and manually clicking on `idea.sh`.

I have tried exporting the current directory PATH, reinstalling and modifying the `idea.properties` file to have: `idea.home.path=/opt/idea-IC-231.8109.175/` to no avail.

Can anyone help? I am running Kubuntu Linux.